# Xcode 4.2 Simulator Crash Log

Tags: iphone, xcode4, crash, xcode4.2, crash-log

Is there a crash log generated by apps that crash on the simulator. I want a text-based version of what I see in the debugger equivalent to crash reports generated by applications crashing on a device (and accessible through Organiser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/`.

**EDIT** Please note that this question was specifically asked for **Xcode 4.2**, which contained the iOS 5.0 SDK.  This is no longer the latest Xcode/iOS SDK, so you'll have to adjust the answer to suite the SDK version you have installed (i.e. change "5.0" to whatever it is).

Comment: Generally, I don't think it's necessarily negative to have an answer downvoted. IMO, it's more of a negative for people searching Google to stumble upon outdated answers, and end up wasting time. It's just a practical thing, that's all.

Comment: Not sure why suddenly you feel the need to provoke me. I'm just trying to make this question a better resource. Xcode 4.2 is no longer distributed by Apple, and 5.0 is no longer the default SDK, so I'm not quite sure what you're getting at. A lot of newbies wouldn't know this.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite actual, but I found them in `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`
Also, they can be viewed through `Console` utility in `User Diagnostic Reports` tab.